# PHP5 database password and can it be stolen?

Tags: php, database, passwords

Hello guys I'm new to php and I discovered that for a database connection you input your password directly into .php file ("mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db"). I read about hashing and I'm going to use hashing but the question is can the user download the precompiled .php file and view my source code and therefore get my database password. If he writes "domain/home" i have an index.php file which prevents the user from entering the directory.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Off topic: the mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. Switch to mysqli or [PDO](http://php.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by other answerers, normally this shouldn't be a problem since users won't be able to see the PHP code. If, however, you plan to share the code with others, it can be a bit of a hassle to remove the username and password before sending it to somebody (and, if you forget they'll know your password).

So, you could put the info in a file and then read it into PHP. For example, create a file called `mysql.ini` in your home directory and put the following information in it:

```
host     = "127.0.0.1"
username = "user"
password = "pass"
database = "db"
```

Then, read it into PHP and connect, like this:

```
$settings = parse_ini_file('/home/mysql.ini');
mysql_connect($settings['host'], $settings['username'], $settings['password'], $settings['database']);
```

Remember to make sure that the file is in a section of the web server that is not publicly accessible, though, otherwise people will be able to read your login info.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot hash the MySQL password and still connect to the database. If you could connect with a hashed password, an attacker could get the hash and connect just as well. Hashing (even better when salted) is a good thing for if you're storing passwords for your users in a database, but isn't really usable when storing database credentials.

Most people, rather than directly including a `mysql_connect` call with all the credentials in their main application file, would at least `require` a configuration file from outside the document root containing the credentials.

If you have a file like `config.php` outside of the document root, then unless they can find a directory traversal hole in the server, `config.php` cannot be accessed remotely.

Answer (score 3):

> can the user download the precompiled .php file

Not through mod_php itself, but if there is some security vulnerability in the web application (or the web server) then someone could certainly read random PHP files.  If the attacker can break into the web server, then they can retrieve the database password -- yes, even if you store it outside of the web root.

**You should assume that this will happen some day**; try to limit the consequences of such an information leak.  Focus on restricting the database account you connect with.  A web application should not be connecting to a database account that has read/write access to every table in the database.  You should restrict the DB user so it can only read from tables it needs to read from, and only write to tables that it needs to write to.

Using stored procedures is a good way to add an additional layer of security, since you can perform checks in the database itself regarding what actions the site user is allowed to perform.  Then the web DB user should only be able to interact with the database through procedures.  This would limit the actions that an attacker could take even if he was able to issue random database queries.

Answer (score 2):

view source of your php page- see any php code? you shouldn't its run by the server before being sent to the users browser. still it is recommended you put the file with the login details below the web root, in case something breaks on the server and php files are not parsed.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they were very helpful :)